# Using Opengl Vertices(coordinates) as a hot spot

Tags: android, opengl-es

### I have drawn a board in opengl, and now want to know that,

1. How can i translate or map the vertices(coordinates) of the board to
   device' pixel so that i can make use of these vertices as a point of
   work for all android devices, do i need this translation or not?
2. The reason i asked above question is that I want to place images over these vertices (that is over current `GLSUrfaceView` where board is drawn), can i do so, if yes kindly guide me a bit?
3. Thanks for your patience!

Comment: I fail to understand what your question is. Are you drawing a 3D object on android device with openGL and you would like to know how to get vertex position projected to screen in screen coordinates as in a vertex displayed in upper left corner should give result of (0,0)? If so, what exactly do you need, only a center and scale (possibly rotation), all the vertices, whole point cloud...?

Comment: Thanks [Matic Oblak](http://stackoverflow.com/users/526828/matic-oblak) for your reply, actually,I have drawn a board by connecting the vertices in opengl, now, i want to place the pieces/images on these vertices

Comment: but i do not know how to do transformation from vertices coordinates to device' pixel coordinates and does opengl for android provide any function to place images using coordinates system

Comment: If you are trying to draw an image bound to some vertices, what you are looking for is called texture. As for getting the screen coordinates you would need to get the matrix from the GL (or recreate it on your own) then multiply the vectors (vertices) with it.